# Python add a space between special characters and words

Tags: python, string, join, split

I am working on a data science project and I have an issue. I have an array full of string like the following string and I want to add a space between the words and between the special characters

```
sentence[i] = 'This is a⓵⓶⓷string'
```

and I expect something like that:

```
sentence[i] = 'This is a ⓵ ⓶ ⓷ string'
```

My last try:

```
l=[]
for i in lines:
    for j in i:
        if j.isalpha() == False:
            l.append(i.split())
        else:
            l.append(i)

print(l)

for i in l:
    s = ' '.join(i)
```

Comment: have you tried to solve this?

Comment: yes with split join methods but its too hard for me...

Comment: with other unicode characters i dont have that issue

Comment: why i take a negative vote again ???

Comment: Can you show a code you tried ? Maybe that's why someone downvote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply scan the complete line and selectively add space for each character that is neither alphabet nor a space.

```
s = 'This is a⓵⓶⓷string'
t = ''
for x in s :
    if not str.isalpha(x) and x != ' ' :
        if t[-1] != ' ':
            t+= ' '
        t += x
        t += ' '
    else: t += x
```

this works for example you have given.

Answer (score 0):

Use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) to accomplish that task, specifically `re.sub` together with a *backreference* in order to surround the matched characters with spaces.